# How to check if more than one model/library is installed if not install it?

Tags: python

I want python to install model1 & model2 if they are not already installed

if model1 or model2 doesn't exist then !pip install model1 & !pip install model2

Comment: What is `model1`?  Is that the name of a package?

Comment: model1 argparse & model2 cv2

Answer (score 0):

**The easiest way is to ensure that all modules can be loaded on all systems. Enclosing each import statement in a try block is the best solution and not un-Pythonic at all.**

```
> try:
>     import model1
>     print("module 'model1' is installed") 

> except ModuleNotFoundError:
>     print("module 'model1' is not installed")
>     install("model1") # the install function from the question
```

**Updated Section:-**
If you can just convert into below code than i think no need for each model/library

```
> try:
>   #importing all packages
>   #importing model1
>   #importing model2 
> except ExceptionType1: 
>     #install model1 
> except ExceptionType2:  
>     #install model2
```

Comment: should I apply this to each model/library

Comment: see the updated section. Try to import all the packages in try block and than apply except block for every package.

Comment: thank you I want to apply !pip install but it doesn't work inside the except is there an alternative way ?

Comment: sorry I don't know any alternative way.. but yeah if i get any way i will ensure you.!

Answer (score 0):

this will do.

```
import importlib

# List of libraries to check and potentially install
libraries_to_check = ["library1", "library2", "library3"]

# Check if each library is installed, and install if not
for library in libraries_to_check:
    try:
        importlib.import_module(library)
        print(f"{library} is already installed.")
    except ImportError:
        print(f"{library} is not installed. Installing...")
        try:
            import subprocess
            subprocess.check_call(["pip", "install", library])
            print(f"{library} has been successfully installed.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred while installing {library}: {e}")
```